# tensorflow slim modify resnet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I want to modify the resnet_v2.resnet_v2_50 model so that I concatenate a number to the pool5 layer.
After I import the network I can see the layers in the end_points variable.

```
    with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v2.resnet_arg_scope()):
        net, end_points = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_50(self.imageIn, num_classes = numClasses)
```

So I have access to the different layers

```
curr_conv1 = end_points['resnet_v2_50/conv1']
curr_pred = end_points['resnet_v2_50/predictions']
curr_block4 = end_points['mainQN/resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2']
```

But I don't have access to the last part of the network after the pooling layer.

```
curr_pool5 = end_points['resnet_v2_50/pool5']
```

But I can see in Tensorboard and in the code of resnet_v2_50 that there is some kind of pool5 layer. How can I get access to it, so I can modify it and concatenate a number to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
end_points['global_pool']
```

is what you want. That immediately follows the global pooling layer called pool5 in the code.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py#L214